# After high-speed mining, unicoin rocks stopped giving coins

Tags: support, unicoins

I have asked my friend Auto Hot Key (call him Hottie) to help me with mining unicoins, but he was so fast in clicking, that rocks soon stopped to contain any coins. How I can politely ask them to give coins again?

Comment: You hit the daily coin cap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait 10 minutes.

If you view the "page" returned by the Ajax query you'll see the error message.